# regular expresion to get tomcat connector

Tags: regex

I has been breaking my head trying with regular expresions. I want to extract the sslconnector in a tomcat service.xml file.

this is the imput from my file.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="${shutdown.port}" shutdown="5ijXSyVl4Y9r">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">



    <Connector port="${http.port}" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="${https.port}" />


         <Connector port="${https.port}" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/opt/ais/install/tomcat/security/ais.jks" keystorePass="a1ss3cr3t"
               clientAuth="false" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />


    <Connector port="${ajp.port}" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="${https.port}" connectionTimeout="20000"/>
    <Connector port="${ajp.port}" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="${https.port}" connectionTimeout="20000"/>



    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="${tomcat.node.name}">


      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="access_log" pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %D %I %{JSESSIONID}c" resolveHosts="false" rotatable="false"/>

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I was trying with this sed sentence. "**sed  -n '/<.*[Cc]onnector.*/>/p'**" but not look, I'm only able to get the ajp connector.

some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following (GNU) `sed` might work :

```
sed -n '/<Connector /,/\/>/p'
```

It prints from the line containing `<Connector`  up to the line containing the next `/>` (which can be the same line).

It works with your sample data but could fail under many conditions, such as the tag having children and being closed by a `</Connector>` rather than self-closing. If your data has enough variation you'll probably want to use an XML selection language such as XPath, in which `//Connector` would be enough to get you all the Connector nodes whatever their format is.